# How to use a template template argument from a member templated type alias of a struct

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

I'm trying to use a template template argument coming from a member type alias of a struct, but I can't find the right syntax:

```
struct A
{
   template <typename T>
   using type = int;
};

template <template <typename> class C>
struct B
{
   // ...
};

B<typename A::type> b; // Does not compile: error: template argument for template template parameter must be a class template or type alias template
B<typename A::template type> b; // Does not compile: error: expected an identifier or template-id after '::'
B<typename A::template <typename> type> b; // Does not compile
B<typename A::template <typename> class type> b; // Does not compile
```

Comment: Try `B<A::type> b;`

Comment: @JeJo I imagine I could use a different design, is it a known c++ limitation?

Comment: @cigien This also results in `error: template argument for template template parameter must be a class template or type alias template`

Comment: It seems [ok](https://godbolt.org/z/TcqxWExdo). What compiler, version, and flags are you using?

Comment: @cigien I'm using `Apple clang version 11.0.0 (clang-1100.0.33.16)`
Though, as noted below `B<A::template type> b` is working for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`A::type` is a template, not a typename.

```
B<A::template type> b1;  // OK
B<A::type> b2;           // OK
```

Comment: I'm not sure exactly why but in my case only the first proposition works (`b1`).
Anyway, thank you very much!

Comment: @user2237143 Perhaps the real code of A is a bit different.

Comment: You're right, in my case `A` is itself a templated class. Does that make a difference?